# Two beans with the same name results in ConflictingBeanDefinitionException despite using @Primary

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, spring-ioc

I have an application initializer class that is used to insert application specific data to database.

```
@Component("applicationInitializer")
public class ApplicationInitializer {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        // some clever code here
    }
}
```

There is also `DevApplicationInitializer` class that is used to initialize database with some sample data on developer machine (this class is excluded when deploying production code).

```
@Component("applicationInitializer")
@Primary
public class DevApplicationInitializer extends ApplicationInitializer {
    @PostConstruct
    @Override
    public void init(){
        super.init();
        // even more clever code here
    }
}
```

Until I have given a name for the beans (only the `@Component` annotations) - everything worked fine - when `DevApplicationInitializer` was available, it was instantiated instead of `ApplicationInitializer`. When I gave them an `applicationInitializer` name, the exception is being thrown:

```
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: 
Annotation-specified bean name 'applicationInitializer' for bean class
[com.example.DevApplicationInitializer] conflicts with existing, non-compatible 
bean definition of same name and class [com.example.ApplicationInitializer]
```

Why the `@Primary` annotation is not respected when beans have name? I need them to have one, because I ensure in other place that the initializer has been instantiated with `@DependsOn("applicationInitializer")` annotation.

Comment: How are these beans being registered/scanned?

Comment: In XML config there is `<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />`.

Comment: This problem is usually solved using profiles, see @Profile annotation.

Comment: @JoseLuisMartin, thanks for refreshing my memory about profiles. That is exactly what I've been looking for! It allows me to override bean by name.

Comment: Also note that xml bean definitions always override scanned ones.

Comment: Can you post your ideas as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@Primary` has no relation to bean names. The javadoc states

> Indicates that a bean should be given preference when multiple
>   candidates are qualified to autowire a single-valued dependency.

This only applies to a context containing two beans of some type `A` where a bean of type `B` requires an `A` to be injected. The A bean annotated with `@Primary` will have priority.

Bean ids/names for a given type must be unique. (Bean definitions with the same name can overwrite each other for the same bean type. For example, this would happen if you component scanned a class annotated with `@Component` but also provided a `@Bean` method for that same type.)